# Jquery load() failing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the dimensions of an image but getting e.g.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31Xu1OBZxvL._SL500_AA300_.jpg
```

The code I'm using first checks to see if `image.display_height` variable is null or empty and if so then load the image and get dimensions. If that fails hide the parent.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
if(!!image.display_height) {

    $(image.preview2).load(function(){
        var width =    $(this).width();
        var height =    $(this).height();
    }).error(function (){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    })

}
```

Comment: please submit the html code. Can you see the duplicate "!" in you if statement ??

Comment: What is "image"? Where and how is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code should be like this i guess

image.preview2 should be in quote

```
 $("image.preview2").load(function(){
        var width =    $(this).width();
        var height =    $(this).height();
    }).error(function (){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Replce !! to single !

like this :- 
if(!image.display_height)

Comment: !! checks if a variable is empty OR null

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to check the event object and make sure that you loaded what you think is the proper image

`.load( handler(eventObject) )`

and also i believe that your selector should be in quotes.

```
 $("image.preview2").load(function(){
```